# trigger on user object to update fields in task object

Tags: trigger, user

I am looking if we can write a trigger on user object to update the task object fields, need is to update the task owner field whenever the user name is changed.

Looking for help,

Thanks,

Savyasachi

Comment: This is doable. What you have tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I have never heard any such requirement, probably because you might have a text field. If you use a lookup field, its name would be updated automatically.

Comment: @ Rahul Sharma, it is text field, we do not have lookup

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do in your trigger is to check whether the user name changed, and if so, you have to query the tasks that have your text field as the Id of the user who changed the username.

this is a sample solution:

```
trigger <your_trigger_name> on User (after update,...) {
List<Task> tasksToUpdate=  new List<tasksToUpdate>();

for(User newUser : Trigge.new){
    User oldUser = trigger.oldMap.get(newUser.Id);

    if(newUser.username != oldUser.username) {
        for(Task tsk :[select Id, <your_text_field>,... from Task where <your_text_field> = newUser.Id]){
            // Here you modify the filds you want
            ...

            // Adn then add tehe Task to the list of updates
            tasksToUpdate.add(tsk);
        }
    }
}

if(!tasksToUpdate.isEmpty()){
    update tasksToUpdate;
}
```

}

I hope this helps you